# Force Mercurial to always use --subrepos

Tags: mercurial, subrepos

Is it possible to configure Mercurial to always check subrepos?

I'd like it enabled all the time without having to specify it on the command each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [alias](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias) to do this.  Add entries to your `.hg/hgrc` like:

```
[alias]
status = status --subrepos
add = add --subrepos
...
```

And so on for the other subrepo-aware commands that you want.  Looking at the help text for `hg help subrepos`, that would be add, archive, commit (I'm using v1.8.1 and it commits subrepos by default, but I seem to recall that earlier versions didn't), diff, incoming, outgoing, pull, push, status and update.